# Permissions in Docker volume

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-volume, docker-container, docker-image

I am struggling with permissions on docker volume, I get access denied for writing.

This is a small part of my docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y \
apt-transport-https \
build-essential \
ca-certificates  \
curl \
vim && \............

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - && apt-get install -y nodejs

# Add non-root user
ARG USER=user01
RUN useradd -Um -d /home/$USER -s /bin/bash $USER && \
apt install -y python3-pip && \
pip3 install qrcode[pil]

#Copy that startup.sh into the scripts folder
COPY /scripts/startup.sh /scripts/startup.sh

#Making the startup.sh executable
RUN chmod -v +x /scripts/startup.sh

#Copy node API files
COPY --chown=user1 /node_api/* /home/user1/

USER $USER
WORKDIR /home/$USER

# Expose needed ports
EXPOSE 3000

VOLUME /data_storage

ENTRYPOINT [ "/scripts/startup.sh" ]
```

Also a small part of my startup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/share/lib/provision.py --enterprise-seed $ENTERPRISE_SEED > config.json
```

Then my docker builds command:

```
sudo docker build -t mycontainer .
```

And the docker run command:

```
sudo docker run -v data_storage:/home/user01/.client -p 3008:3000 -itd mycontainer
```

The problem I have is that the Python script will create the folder: /home/user01/.client and it will copy some files in there. That always worked fine. But now I want those files, which are data files, in a volume for backup porpuses. And as I am mapping with my volume I get permissions denied, so the python script is not able to write anymore.

So at the end of my dockerfile this instructions combined with the mapping in the docker run command give me the permission denied:

```
VOLUME /data_storage
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve this? some more permissions needed for the "user01"?
Thanks

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: Working in linux VM ubuntu

Comment: Has directory been created in your system?

Comment: If you're mounting in a local volume, it will use the same numeric UID & GID for filesystem permissions as on the host system. The problem is likely that your `user01` user doesn't use a UID / GID that has write permissions for your locally-mounted volume. Try creating a group in your dockerfile with an explicit GID, then granting your local directory write permissions on that GID.

Comment: @Grzegorz Pudłowski : I create the volume in my dockerfile "VOLUME /data_storage" , then I do the mapping in my docker file. I don't create any file localy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue by removing the "volume" command from the dockerfile and just doing the mapping at the moment of executing the docker run:

sudo docker run -v data_storage:/home/user01/.client -p 3008:3000 -itd mycontainer